# Specialized Tricross Sport size guide?

Tags: bike-fit, specialized-bikes

I have an old Specialized from 2009, it seem pretty fine across the year, but I think the frame is too big for me. I adapt my body other the year, ride a lot, and doesn't make discomfort. After a big pause of riding, now after a one ride I have a big back pain. I thinking that problem is about drop bars, then I ride low at the end of the bars, if I'll change the bars to something like "KOGA Denham Bars" and shorter stem. I mostly touring on my bike, I'm for comfort. The frame size XL Top tube 57.5cm, Seat tube 58cm, Stem 14cm. I'm 185m. don't judge my english.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try riding on the hoods for a while, see if you still get some back pain issues. It doesn’t sound like a bike fit issue if you was riding before with out issues.

Comment: I was riding with out issues but a little discomfort was when i ride at low position, at the end of the drop bars. Then i stay at the top of drop bars, more vertically it's fine,